# VBA - Concatenate multiple rows based on x value while identifying duplicates and sorting in cell values

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, concatenation

Let me start by saying I have been digging on forum sites for a few days now before posting this question but nothing has quite worked the way i need it to.

My situation is i have a 8 column table with a variable number of rows that I need combine according to x value in a selective and sorted way in preparation for a mail merge label.

**Here's what I need to do**

**1.** Combine values in columns **A**,**B**,**C**,**D**, and **F** into one row for each unique value in **H**

**2.** Either skip or remove duplicate values in **A**,**B**,**C**, and **D**

**3.**
    Column **F** needs to keep only the latest Date and should only have one value.

**4.** Column **A** needs to have each unique entry sorted in order oldest to newest. Column **D** should be sorted smallest to largest.

I have a start but I cant figure out how to qualify what gets combined so there aren't duplicate values or how to sort the order certain column values are combined in. I'm a novice VBA coder so I'm probably not going about this the best way but is it even possible?

My table data is pulled out of a much larger table on another sheet via macro. I also have another macro on this sheet to populate this table with similar data based on another criteria for a different merge so in cell formulas aren't a viable option to concatenate.

Here's roughly what the table looks like:

```
0 |  A       |     B     |    C     |   D   |   E   |    F     | G  |  H   |
1 |Item Date | Contents  |addtl cont|Item ID| Dept. |Keep2 Date|box#|pallet|
2 |12/8/2017 | Item1     |          |CBE-32 | Dept. | Forever  |  6 |  16  |
3 |12/8/2017 | Item2     |          |CBE-19 | Dept. |Dec 8 2019|  4 |  16  |
4 |12/8/2017 | Item3     |          |CBE-32 | Dept. | Forever  |  3 |  16  |
5 |12/8/2017 | Item4     |          |CBE-44 | Dept. |Dec 8 2022|  4 |  17  |
6 |12/8/2017 | Item5     |          |CBE-107| Dept. |Feb 6 2018|  1 |  17  |
7 |11/8/2017 | Item6     |  Item7   |CBE-19 | Dept. |Nov 8 2019|  6 |  17  |
```

I managed to adapt a macro to combine my rows together grouped by pallet number in "H".

```
    Sub mergeCategoryValues() 
    Dim lngRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 8 ' pallet number
        Dim columnToConcatenate1 As Integer: columnToConcatenate1 = 1 'election date
        Dim columnToConcatenate2 As Integer: columnToConcatenate2 = 2 'contents
        Dim columnToConcatenate3 As Integer: columnToConcatenate3 = 3 'additional contents/dates
        Dim columnToConcatenate4 As Integer: columnToConcatenate4 = 4 'DAS number
        Dim columnToConcatenate5 As Integer: columnToConcatenate5 = 6 'retention date
        Dim columnToSum As Integer: columnToSum = 7 'not working! should sum total boxes

        lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

        Do
            If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate1) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate1) & Chr(10) & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate1)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate2) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate2) & Chr(10) & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate2)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate3) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate3) & Chr(10) & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate3)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate4) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate4) & Chr(10) & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate4)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate5) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate5) & Chr(10) & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate5)
                .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    'End With
End Sub
```

What this leaves me with is a table like this:

```
 0 |  A       |     B     |    C     |   D   |   E   |    F     | G  |  H   |
 1 |Item Date | Contents  |addtl cont|Item ID| Dept. |Keep2 Date|box#|pallet|
   |12/8/2017 | Item1     |          |CBE-32 |       | Forever  |  6 |      |
 2 |12/8/2017 | Item2     |          |CBE-19 | Dept. |Dec 8 2019|    |  16  |
   |12/8/2017 | Item3     |          |CBE-32 |       | Forever  |    |      |
   |12/8/2017 | Item4     |          |CBE-44 |       |Dec 8 2022|  4 |      |
 3 |12/8/2017 | Item5     |          |CBE-107| Dept. |Feb 6 2018|    |  17  |
   |11/8/2017 | Item6     |  Item7   |CBE-19 |       |Nov 8 2019|    |      |
```

What it **should** look like is this:

```
0 |  A       |     B     |    C     |   D   |   E   |    F     | G  |  H   |
1 |Item Date | Contents  |addtl cont|Item ID| Dept. |Keep2 Date|box#|pallet|
  |          | Item1     |          |CBE-19 |       |          |    |      |
2 |12/8/2017 | Item2     |          |CBE-32 | Dept. | Forever  | 13 |  16  |
  |          | Item3     |          |       |       |          |    |      |
  |11/8/2017 | Item4     |          |CBE-19 |       |          |    |      |
3 |12/8/2017 | Item5     |          |CBE-44 | Dept. |Dec 8 2022| 11 |  17  |
  |          | Item6     |  Item7   |CBE-107|       |          |    |      |
```

Right now everything is set to concatenate with a carriage return but I will eventually like to change **A** and **D** to a "**,**" separator.
Column **G** should return the sum for the number of boxes combined according to the adapted code but that data field is not used in the merge so I'm not to worried about that.

Answer (score 0):

Below are 2 classes and some updates to your module that should take a you a long way towards solving the problem.  I hope you find it helpful and good luck.

For your project you'll need to add a reference.  This is found in the VB Editor under **Tools-> References**.  When you click on this, the dialog box below is displayed.  You'll need to select the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

The solution below uses Scripting.Dictionary types to eliminate duplicates.

To add a class to your project, in the VB Editor select item **Insert->Class**.  A new class dialog box appears, copy and past the first class below into this.  Over on the lower left, change the class name from class to clItem

**Class clItem**

```
Option Explicit

Public ItemDate As Date         'Column A
Public Contents As String       'Column B
Public AddlContents As String   'Column C
Public ItemID As String         'Column D
Public Dept As String           'Column E
Public Keep2Date As Variant     'Column F
Public NumBoxes As Long         'Column G
```

Repeat the steps above and paste the code below into the new class.  Change the name from class to clPallet

**Class clPallet**

```
Option Explicit

Public PalletNum As Long    'Column H
Private pvItemDates As Scripting.Dictionary     'Used to hold unique item dates and no duplicates
Private pvItemIds As Scripting.Dictionary       'Used to hold unique item ids and no duplicates
Private pvItemCollection As Collection          'The collection of items on a pallet
Private collectionKey As Long                   'Unique key value for the collection
Private pvKeepForever As Boolean                'Boolean for when the value in column Keep2 Date = Forever and is not a date

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pvItemCollection = New Collection       'Initilize a new collection
    Set pvItemDates = New Scripting.Dictionary  'Initilize a dictionary class to store the item dates
    Set pvItemIds = New Scripting.Dictionary    'Initilize a dictionary class to store the item ids
    collectionKey = 1                           'Initialize the key
    pvKeepForever = False                       'Since the Keep2 Date column seems to have dates and text "Forever" we have
                                                'deal with that condition
End Sub

Public Sub AddItem(ByRef palletItem As clItem)
    pvItemCollection.Add palletItem, CStr(collectionKey)  'add pallet item object to the collection and convert the collectionKey to a string
    If UCase(palletItem.Keep2Date) = "FOREVER" Then pvKeepForever = True    'found text "Forever" in column Keep2 Date
    If Not pvItemDates.Exists(palletItem.ItemDate) Then pvItemDates.Add palletItem.ItemDate, palletItem.ItemDate
    If Not pvItemIds.Exists(palletItem.ItemID) Then pvItemIds.Add palletItem.ItemID, palletItem.ItemID

    collectionKey = collectionKey + 1   'update the key to keep a unique value
End Sub

Public Property Get ItemCollection() As Collection
    Set ItemCollection = pvItemCollection   'return the collection
End Property

'**********************************************
'*  The next set of methods flatten the rows of data into a single row
'**********************************************

'*************************************
'*  This provides a sum of all boxes on the pallet
Public Function GetBoxCount() As Long
    Dim item As clItem
    Dim retVal As Long: retVal = 0
    For Each item In pvItemCollection
        retVal = retVal + item.NumBoxes
    Next item
    GetBoxCount = retVal
End Function
'***************************************
'*  This takes the rows of contents and puts them
'*  into a comma separated string
Public Function GetContents() As String
    Dim item As clItem
    Dim retVal As String
    For Each item In pvItemCollection
        retVal = ConcatStr(item.Contents, retVal)
    Next item

    GetContents = retVal
End Function
'************************************************
'*  This takes the rows of Item Ids and puts them
'*  into a comma separated string
Public Function GetItemIDs() As String
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim retVal As String

    Dim arrList As Object
    Set arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each Key In pvItemIds.Keys
        arrList.Add Key
    Next Key
    arrList.Sort

    Dim sortedItem As Variant
    For Each sortedItem In arrList
        retVal = ConcatStr(CStr(sortedItem), retVal)
    Next sortedItem

    GetItemIDs = retVal
End Function
'************************************************
'*  This takes the rows of Additional Contents and puts them
'*  into a comma separated string
Public Function GetAddlContents() As String
    Dim item As clItem
    Dim retVal As String
    For Each item In pvItemCollection
        retVal = ConcatStr(item.AddlContents, retVal)
    Next item

    GetAddlContents = retVal
End Function
'************************************************
'*  This takes the rows of Departments and puts them
'*  into a comma separated string
Public Function GetDepartments() As String
    Dim item As clItem
    Dim retVal As String
    For Each item In pvItemCollection
        retVal = ConcatStr(item.Dept, retVal)
    Next item

    GetDepartments = retVal
End Function
'************************************************
'*  This gets the last Keep2 Date and returns it
'*  one per pallet
Public Function GetLatestDate() As Variant
    Dim item As clItem
    Dim retVal As Variant

    If pvKeepForever Then
        retVal = "Forever"
    Else
        retVal = DateValue("January 1, 1950")   'Initilize the retVal with an old date
        For Each item In pvItemCollection       'Loop thru the item objects looking for the latest date
            If item.Keep2Date > retVal Then     'if we find one that is further in the future than current
                retVal = item.Keep2Date         'then set that as the latest date
            End If
        Next item
    End If
    GetLatestDate = retVal

End Function
'************************************************
'*  This takes the rows of Item Dates and puts them
'*  into a comma separated string
Public Function GetItemDates() As String
    Dim retVal As String
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In pvItemDates.Keys
        If retVal = "" Then
            retVal = v
        Else
            retVal = retVal & ", " & v
        End If
    Next v
    GetItemDates = retVal
End Function
'************************************************
'*  This private function concatenates a value on to an existing string
Private Function ConcatStr(ByRef itemString As String, ByRef currentVal As String) As String
    Dim retVal As String
    If itemString = "" Then
        retVal = currentVal
    ElseIf currentVal = "" Then
        retVal = itemString
    Else
        retVal = currentVal & ", " & itemString
    End If

    ConcatStr = retVal
End Function
```

For your module, which would be linked to your macro, replace your code with the following:

**Update Module**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const HeadingColA = "Item Date"
Public Const HeadingColB = "Contents"
Public Const HeadingColC = "addtl cont"
Public Const HeadingColD = "Item ID"
Public Const HeadingColE = "Dept."
Public Const HeadingColF = "Keep2 Date"
Public Const HeadingColG = "box#"
Public Const HeadingColH = "pallet"

Public Const PalletDataCol = 8

Public Const TheTableRange = "A1:H7"
Public Const HeadingRowRange = "A1:H1"      'Heading Row
Public Const DataTableRange = "A2:H7"       'Headings are in row 1
Public Const TheSortRange = "H2:H7"
Public Const DataWorkSheetName = "SourceData"
Public Const TargetWorkSheetName = "Transformed"


Public Sub mergeCategoryValues()
    'Declare a workbook variable and set it to the active workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Declare a worksheet variable and set it to the data source worksheet
    Dim srcWs As Worksheet
    Set srcWs = wb.Sheets(DataWorkSheetName)

    'Don't update the screen while this routine is running
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Declare a range that is the data range on the source worksheet
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Set dataRng = srcWs.Range(DataTableRange)
    'Make the source worksheet the active sheet
    srcWs.Activate
    'Sort the range by the Pallet Column in this case H
    SortTheRange TheSortRange, TheTableRange, srcWs

    'Declare a variable for the destination worksheet
    'and create the sheet if it doesn't exist
    Dim destWs As Worksheet
    If SheetExists(TargetWorkSheetName, wb) Then
        Set destWs = wb.Sheets(TargetWorkSheetName)
        destWs.Cells.Clear
    Else
        Set destWs = wb.Sheets.Add
        destWs.Name = TargetWorkSheetName
    End If

    'Copy the headings from the source worksheet to the destination worksheet
    WriteHeadings srcWs, destWs, HeadingRowRange

    'Declare a pallet object of type clPallet (a user defined pallet class named clPallet)
    Dim pallet As clPallet
    Set pallet = New clPallet   'Instantiate the object
    pallet.PalletNum = GetFirstPalletNumber(dataRng(RowIndex:=1, ColumnIndex:=PalletDataCol))

    Dim palletItem As clItem    'Declare a palletItem object of type clItem
    Dim dataRow As Range, dataCol As Range  'set up enumerators to loop thru rows and columns of data
    Dim nextRow As Long: nextRow = 2    'counter to keep advancing the output row on the destination sheet
    For Each dataRow In dataRng.Rows
        If pallet.PalletNum <> dataRow.Value2(1, PalletDataCol) Then    'do we have new pallet?
            WriteData destWs, pallet, nextRow       'yes, then write the current pallet to a row on the destination sheet
            nextRow = nextRow + 1                   'update the output row
            Set pallet = New clPallet               'get new pallet object
            pallet.PalletNum = dataRow.Value2(1, PalletDataCol) 'assign the pallet number to the new pallet object
        End If

        Set palletItem = New clItem     'Instantiate a new pallet item object
        Call AssignPalletItemValues(palletItem, dataRow, srcWs)
        'add the palletItem object to the pallet collection contained in the
        'pallet object
        pallet.AddItem palletItem
    Next dataRow

    'one last write since we exited from the loop above when we reached the
    'last datarow...but we didn't write out the final row of data
    WriteData destWs, pallet, nextRow

    'Turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
'********************************************************************************************************
'*  Private sub copies the headings fromt the source worksheet and writes them to the target worksheet
Private Sub WriteHeadings(ByRef srcWs As Worksheet, ByRef tarWs As Worksheet, ByVal headingRng As String)
    srcWs.Activate                  'Make the source worksheet the active sheet
    Range(headingRng).Select        'Select the range based on the value in the parameter headingRng
    Selection.Copy                  'Copy the selection to the clipboards
    tarWs.Activate                  'Make the target worksheet the active sheet
    Range(headingRng).Select        'Select the target range based on the value in the parameter headingRng
    ActiveSheet.Paste               'Paste the values on the clipboard into the selected range on the target worksheet
    'Set Column E (Keep 2 Date as a short date format
    Columns("F:F").Select               'Select column F
    Application.CutCopyMode = False     'Not copying or cutting
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" 'Set the date format
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
'*  Private function gets the first pallet number from the target sheets column H
Private Function GetFirstPalletNumber(ByRef c As Range) As Long
    GetFirstPalletNumber = c.Value2
End Function
'************************************************************************************************
'*  Private sub writes takes a Pallet class and writes out all the values on one row in the spreadsheet
Private Sub WriteData(ByRef destWs As Worksheet, ByRef pallet As clPallet, ByVal nextRow As Long)
    Dim palletItem As clItem

    destWs.Range("A" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetItemDates        'Item date
    destWs.Range("B" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetContents         'Contents, comma separated
    destWs.Range("C" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetAddlContents     'Additional contents, comma separated
    destWs.Range("D" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetItemIDs          'Item Id's comma separated
    destWs.Range("E" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetDepartments      'Dept.
    destWs.Range("F" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetLatestDate       'Keep 2 date
    destWs.Range("G" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetBoxCount         'Box Count
    destWs.Range("H" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.PalletNum           'Pallet Number

End Sub
'***********************************************************************************
'*  private function checks if sheet exists
'*      Returns True if sheet is in the workbook
'*      Returns false if the sheet is not in the workbook
Private Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
'*************************************************************************************
'*  private sub that adds the data from the source row to a pallet item object
Private Sub AssignPalletItemValues(ByRef palletItem As clItem, ByRef srcRow As Range, ByRef srcWs As Worksheet)
    Dim dataCol As Range
    For Each dataCol In srcRow.Columns
        Select Case srcWs.Cells(1, dataCol.Column).Value2
            Case HeadingColA
                palletItem.ItemDate = dataCol.Value2
            Case HeadingColB
                palletItem.Contents = dataCol.Value2
            Case HeadingColC
                palletItem.AddlContents = dataCol.Value2
            Case HeadingColD
                palletItem.ItemID = dataCol.Value2
            Case HeadingColE
                palletItem.Dept = dataCol.Value2
            Case HeadingColF
                palletItem.Keep2Date = dataCol.Value2
            Case HeadingColG
                palletItem.NumBoxes = dataCol.Value2
        End Select
    Next dataCol
End Sub
'***************************************************************************
'*  private sub sorts the data range given by the parameter tableRange located
'*  on the worksheet given by scrWs using the sorting criteria given by sortRange
Private Sub SortTheRange(ByRef sortRange As String, ByRef tableRange As String, ByRef srcWs As Worksheet)
    With srcWs.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(sortRange), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                              Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range(tableRange)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It took me some time to get back to this project but this helped greatly thank you! Thanks for providing explanation comments.With your help I was able to do 99% of what I needed though I had to modify it to accommodate different table sizes and I added another script to format the contents output with a carriage return. I do however have two questions. First is it possible to have the output data overwrite and replace the source table instead of making a new sheet? Second how can i join the value in "C" with the value in "B" using text like  "and" before the values of "B" are combined?

Comment: I've added another answer below as it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for a delayed response to your question.  I’ve been buried in other projects.

Yes, you can overwrite the source data with the revised data, but I don’t recommend doing that.  A best programming practice is to never overwrite source data. If something goes wrong you might not be able to get the original source and then it would be impossible to figure out what went wrong.  Many times your end user will ask to see the source data or you’ll need it to prove that your output is correct based on what they gave you.

Question 2 demonstrates the beauty of using a class object.

You could simply add the following property to the `clItem` class:

```
Public Property Get ContentAndAddlContent()
    If AddlContents = "" Then
        ContentAndAddlContent = Contents
    Else
        ContentAndAddlContent = Contents & " and " & AddlContents
    End If
End Property
```

Add the following method to the `clPallet` Class.  I’d add if after the methdol Get AddlContents

```
'************************************************
'*  This takes the rows of Additional Contents and ands them with Content
'*  into a comma separated string
Public Function GetAndedContents() As String
     Dim item As clItem
     Dim retVal As String
     For Each item In pvItemCollection
          retVal = ConcatStr(item.ContentAndAddlContent, retVal)
     Next item

     GetAndedContents = retVal
 End Function
```

Then update the  `Private Sub WriteData(ByRef destWs As Worksheet, ByRef pallet As clPallet, ByVal nextRow As Long)` as follows

```
'*******************************************************************
'   Orginial Code - commented out
'destWs.Range("B" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetContents         'Contents, comma separated
'destWs.Range("C" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetAddlContents     'Additional contents, comma separated
'**********************************************************************
'   New Code for adding
If pallet.GetAddlContents = "" Then
    destWs.Range("B" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetContents         'Contents, comma separated
Else
    destWs.Range("B" & Trim(CStr(nextRow))).Value2 = pallet.GetAndedContents    'Contents anded and comma separated
End If
```

You could get fancy and use a constant at the top of the module that would let you change if you use the and or not.  Something like ‘Public Const UseAnd = True` or get even fancier and have a sheet containing control parameters.